# installing eclipse-mars error linux ubuntu Error

Tags: linux, terminal, installation, tar, eclipse-mars

I've downloaded Eclipse with c/c++ through ubuntu, virtual machine running on windows 8 with yoga-2 pro computer. this is the folder I have right now in my downloads folder, with a zip and an extracted folder.
Now I navigate to that folder and run command:

```
 tar -zxvf eclipse-cpp-mars-2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
```

I see some kind of weird Eclipse, something like "an eclipse astronomical event.." and I don't understand how to open it.
...HELP?

Comment: Please describe in more details what happens when you run Eclipse. What do you mean by "I don't understand how to open it."? Can you provide a link where to get the archive you downloaded?

Comment: it basically doesnt downlad anything.. just some kind of elipse with a black circle that doesn't really do anything

Comment: Why should Eclipse download anything? You said you downloaded Eclipse as an archive and extracted its contents, what did you do next? Can you provide a link to where you downloaded this archive?